# Detecting C++0x mode on Intel C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, c-preprocessor, intel, conditional-compilation

Does Intel C++ predefine some macro when compiling with `Qstd=c++0x`? Something like  `__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__` in GCC? `__cplusplus` is still `199711`.

Any way to detect C++0x compilation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Intel documentation indicates](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/ISO-CPP0x-detection-during-compilation/) that it does define `__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__` on Linux, but does not define any macro on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

On the current (2013-08-06) Intel Composer XE 2013 Update 5 for Windows, the list of preprocessor definitions includes

```
#define __INTEL_CXX11_MODE__ 1
```

if and only if C++0x mode is enabled.